How to derive likelihood function
I have been struggling a lot with the concept of likelihood and I'd really appreciate it if someone could verify if my understanding is correct and give input.

If I understand this correcly, we pick a point on x and then asks ourselves given the data on this exact x point in this case $x_0$, what is the likelihood that we observe a data point t, as in which parameter are most likely to obsreved and if we keep doing that for all x points then we can approximate the function for the likeli hood?

The likelihood is just the negative log of the conditional distribution of the observation given some parameter value. Computing this required you to specify some statistical model relating parameters to oberservations

Here is a somewhat intuitive answer to hopefully help you understand the concept:

the likelihood of an event is simply the probability of that event being observed: the likelihood of "Heads" on a fair coin is 1/2, the likelihood of getting a "6" on a fair 6-sided die is 1/6.
if you have a sequence of events, you can ask the same sort of question: the likelihood of getting 3 "Heads" (and 1 "Tail") out of 4 flips of a fair coin is $4\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1\right)=\frac14$ because there are 4 ways of choosing 3 heads with 4 successive flips ({{H,H,H,T},{H,H,T,H},{H,T,H,H},{T,H,H,H}}). The key here is that the draws are independent (and drawn from an identical distribution, that of the fair coin), and thus the probabilities are multiplied.
if you were then to play this game of heads and tails with someone you do not trust to use a fair coin, you might be interested in estimating the true parameter $p=\mathbb{P}(X=H)$ for the distribution of the coin. Say you get tails 5 times out of 6 flips, that does not mean that the coin is not fair as you could have been (un)lucky. That said, you might ask "which parameter p is the maximum likelihood estimation of the parameter p"? In other words, which parameter best explains the sequence of events observed. To do so, one approach would be to do a grid of all possible values of p and see which one gives you the highest probability: say you have a grid $p=\{0,0.01,0.02,\cdots,0.99,1\}$.

Let $Y$ be the r.v. counting the number of heads.
Using $p=\frac12$, you would get $\mathbb{P}(Y=5|p=\frac12)=6\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5\right)\approx9\%$;
Using e.g. $p=\frac{1}{10}$ you get $\mathbb{P}(Y=5|p=\frac{1}{10})=6\left(\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^1\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^5\right)\approx35\%$
As you can see, it is more "likely" that the true parameter be $p=\frac{1}{10}$ rather than $p=\frac{1}{2}$. To clarify what this likelihood means: it is more likely to observe the sequence of events detailed with a coin having $p=\frac{1}{10}$.
So as you can see, searching this grid and finding for which parameter $p$ the likelihood is highest would give you an approximate "best guess" as to what the true parameter might be. If you were to do this, you would find that the maximum likelihood estimator is in fact the mean number of observations of the event, i.e. 1/6 in this case. Plotting the function yields the following picture, which visually confirms this:



One way to solve this without having this "grid" consists in "maximizing the likelihood". This can sometimes be done analytically, and if not it can be done numerically. The way to do this is, as was done above, to write the probability of obtaining the sequence of events, as a function of p, and then to maximize it. With the independence assumption stated earlier, probabilities are multiplied, hence taking the log transforms this into a summation, which is usually easier to maximize analytically (note that log is a strictly increasing function, hence maximizing the log-likelihood is an equivalent problem to that of maximizing the likelihood). This is why often times we write the log-likelihood rather than the likelihood.
In the above graph, the joint likelihood function is $f(p)=p(1-p)^5$. Maximizing is achieved with first order condition $f'(p)=0$, which yields $-6 (-1 + p)^4 (-1 + 6 p)=0$ and solves for $p=\{\frac16,1\}$. The second order condition looks at the second derivative $f''(p)=-60 (-1 + x)^3 (-1 + 3 x)$, and plugging in both candidate values we wee that it is negative for $p=\frac16$ only, making that the unique maximum likelihood estimate. Using the log in this case was avoided, but writing $k$ the number of heads and $n$ the number of flips, you can see how having $f(p)=\prod_{h=1}^{k}p\prod_{t=1}^{n-k}(1-p)$, for other distributions, might become more complex to derive analytically. In our example, the log-likelihood would become $\log f(p)=k\log(p)+(n-k)\log(1-p)$, with the derivative being $\frac{k-np}{p(1-p)}$ canceling at $p=k/n$ once again.

I hope this clarifies your understanding. Your comments appear to show very decent understanding of what a likelihood is, so keep the faith, you are on the right path :-) As you state, you do that for all the x's that you observe, assuming x is your data (i.e. the realizations of your r.v.). The one thing that is perhaps slightly misunderstood is the concept of likelihood vs likelihood function, as you say "if we keep doing that for all x points then we can approximate the function for the likelihood?". - Writing the probability (using the density of your events' distribution) for each point and multiplying those will give you the true "joint distribution";

by "joint", we simply mean the multi-dimensional version of your 1-event distribution. So if you observe 10 events, you have a 10-D distribution.
if you use the "grid" approach described above, for each value tested, you will get a probability (the joint probability for all 10 events), so a number, not a function.
however if you write the multiplication of your different densities analytically, you will get the exact likelihood function: a new density for observing a 10-dimensional random variable corresponding to your problem. If the maximization can be done analytically, then the obtained "maximum likelihood estimation" of your parameter will therefore be exact.

